# How to use property key value in servlet

Tags: java, properties, key

I have a multi-language system that works with property files, and in the .jsp files I am calling the values like so: `<fmt:message key="welcome"/>`

This works only in .jsp files.

How would I got about doing the same directly in Java class files (Servlets), is it even possible?

Comment: You may want to use a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) to read property file.
For Example :

```
ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("FILENAME", Locale.getDefault());
```

Second parameter `Locale.getDefault()` is your [language code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).
for example   `Locale.ENGLISH` or `Locale.FRENCH` etc.

You can read properties by

```
  myResources.getString("Your paramName or Key");
```

I hope this will help you.